# wxAuiNotebook - preventing certain tabs from closing

Tags: wxpython

I'm experimenting with wx.aui.AuiNotebook; is there a way I can prevent particular tabs from being closed? i.e. I have an app that allows the user to create multiple tabs in an AuiNotebook, but the first 2 tabs are system managed and I don't want them to be closed.

Also, in a close event, can I get the window object attached to the tab being closed? (to extract data from it)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation where I wanted to prevent the user from closing the last tab. What I did was binding the `wx.aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSE` event and then in the event handler check for the number of tabs open. If the number of tabs is less than two I toggle the `wx.aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ACTIVE_TAB` style so that the last tab doesn't have a close button.

```
class MyAuiNotebook(wx.aui.AuiNotebook):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['style'] = kwargs.get('style', wx.aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE) & \
            ~wx.aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ACTIVE_TAB
        super(MyAuiNotebook, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Bind(wx.aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSE, self.onClosePage)

    def onClosePage(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        if self.GetPageCount() <= 2:
            # Prevent last tab from being closed
            self.ToggleWindowStyle(wx.aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ACTIVE_TAB)

    def AddPage(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyAuiNotebook, self).AddPage(*args, **kwargs)
        # Allow closing tabs when we have more than one tab:
        if self.GetPageCount() > 1:
            self.SetWindowStyle(self.GetWindowStyleFlag() | \
                wx.aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ACTIVE_TAB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very late and I am using `wx.lib.agw.aui`. But perhaps is useful for someone else.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.aui as aui 

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, wx.ID_ANY, "1 & 2 do not close")

        self.reportDown = aui.auibook.AuiNotebook(
            self,
            agwStyle=aui.AUI_NB_TOP|aui.AUI_NB_TAB_SPLIT|aui.AUI_NB_TAB_MOVE|aui.AUI_NB_SCROLL_BUTTONS|aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ALL_TABS|aui.AUI_NB_MIDDLE_CLICK_CLOSE|aui.AUI_NB_DRAW_DND_TAB,
        )
        self.reportDown.AddPage(wx.Panel(self.reportDown), '1, I do not close')
        self.reportDown.AddPage(wx.Panel(self.reportDown), '2, I do not close')     
        self.reportDown.AddPage(wx.Panel(self.reportDown), '3, I do close')

        #--> For this to work you must include aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ALL_TABS
        #--> in the agwStyle of the AuiNotebook
        # Remove close button from first tab
        self.reportDown.SetCloseButton(0, False)
        # Remove close button from second tab 
        self.reportDown.SetCloseButton(1, False)        

        self._mgr = aui.AuiManager()

        self._mgr.SetManagedWindow(self)

        self._mgr.AddPane(
            self.reportDown, 
            aui.AuiPaneInfo(
                ).Center(
                ).Caption(
                    '1 & 2 do not close'
                ).Floatable(
                    b=False
                ).CloseButton(
                    visible=False
                ).Movable(
                    b=False
            ),
        )

        self._mgr.Update()
    #---
#---
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```